# Understanding inner class in Java

Tags: java, class

Consider the following class:

```java
package test;

public class Container {
    public class Contained {
        public void foo() {
            System.out.println("printed");
        }
    }
}
```

and the Main.java:

```java
package test;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Container c = new Container();
    }
}
```

So, we right here have created the instance of the `Container` class. Does it mean that we've also created the instance of the inner class? I thought, yes it does, because the inner class is a `non-static` nested class. But how can we get access to the instance of the inner class? Can we ever create the instance outside of the `Container` class?

It would be very useful if you provided some references to the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To instantiate an inner class, you must first instantiate the outer class. Then, create the inner object within the outer object with this syntax:

```java
OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();
```

So in your case it will be

```java
Container container = new Container();
Container.Contained containedClass = container.new Contained();
```

This is called Inner Class. In inner class you can access the container class members

**To create an object for the static nested class, use this syntax:**

```java
 OuterClass.StaticNestedClass nestedObject = new OuterClass.StaticNestedClass();
```

This is called Static Nested Class. In Static Nested Class you can not access the container class instance members but only static members

Answer (score 2):

Creating an instance of `Container` doesn't create an instance of the `Contained` class, since there can many many instances of `Contained` associated with the same instance of `Container`. You create instances of `Contained` explicitly.

Yes, you can create an instance outside `Container` class by specifying the instance of `Container` that would be associated with it :

```
Container cr = new Container();
Container.Contained cd = cr.new Contained ();
```

Inner classes are described in [JLS 8.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3).

Comment: it should be cr.new Contained() not cr.new Container.Contained Is n't it ?